# doing for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a file that I have filtered my SNPs for LD (in the example below;my.filtered.snp.id). I want to keep only these SNPs in my genotype matrix (geno_snp), I am trying to write a for loops in R, and I would appreciate any help to fix my code. I want to keep those lines (the whole line including snp.id and genotype information) in the genotype matrix where snp.id matches with snp.id in my my.filtered.snp.id and delete those that are not match.

```
head(my.filtered.snp.id)
    Chr10_31458
    Chr10_31524
    Chr10_45901
    Chr10_102754
    Chr10_102828
    Chr10_103480

head (geno_snp)
XRQChr10_103805 NA NA NA 0 NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA 0 0
XRQChr10_103937 NA NA NA 0 NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA 0 2
XRQChr10_103990 NA NA NA 0 NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA 0 NA
```

I am trying something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(geno_snp[,1])){
  for (j in 1:length(my.filtered.snp.id)){
   if geno_snp[i,] == my.filtered.snp.i[j]
    print (the whole line in geno_snp)
  }
else (remove the line)
  }
```

Comment: Please use `dput(my.filtered.snp.id)` to provide a reproducible example of all of your inputs. It's unclear if you have a character vector, list, or data.frame.

Comment: Don't you just want something like `my.filtered.snp.id[my.filtered.snp.id %in% geno_snp[,1]]`?

Comment: no, it does not give the output that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want a subset of your data.frame `geno_snp` in which the row names must match the selected SNP IDs from the vector `my.filtered.snp.id`.

Please check if this solution works for you:

```
index <- unlist(sapply(row.names(geno_snp), function(x) grep(pattern = x, x = my.filtered.snp.id)))

selected_subset <- geno_snp[index,]
```

What I did was to create an index adressing the rows with names that were a match with any value in `my.filtered.snp.id`. Then I used the index to make the subset of the dataframe. Since the result from applying the `grep` function with the aid of `sapply` was in the form of a list, I used `unlist` to obtain the results in the form of a vector.

EDIT:

I noticed you had some row.names that weren't an exact match with your original `my.filtered.snp.id` values. In this case, maybe what you wanna do is:

```
index <- unlist(sapply(my.filtered.snp.id, function(x) grep(pattern = x, x = row.names(geno_snp))))
selected_subset <- geno_snp[index,]
```

The thing is that you have row.names beggining with `XRQ`... so in this last case the code uses the reference values from `my.filtered.snp.id` to detect matches in `row.names(geno_snp)`, even if there is this `XRQ` string in the beggining of it.

Finally, in the case I have misunderstood your data and what I'm calling row names here are, in fact, data in a column (the SNP IDs), just use `geno_snp[,1]` instead of `row.names(geno_snp)` in both codes above.